# recyclerview animation not showing

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

it's my first approach to animations in android but i don't understand why it doesn't work.

my main_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout37"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayoutButtons">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_slide_from_right"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

my slide_from_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<set
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:duration="600">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0">
</translate>

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.5"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1">
</alpha>
```

my layout_animation_slide_from_right:

```
<layoutAnimation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/slide_from_right"
    android:animationOrder="normal"
    android:delay="10%">
</layoutAnimation>
```

This is the only thing in the console:

```
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xec079190 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xf27af970
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: add this line after every notifyDatasetChanged() call and it will work!

```
recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
```